# How can I override the default error message in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-validation

I have a Person object with a lastName field. The lastName field cannot be blank. When the user submits a form blank value in the lastName field, the error message that the user sees is:

```
Property [lastName] of class [com.example.Person] cannot be blank
```

This error message is lame. I want to customize it to something more user friendly, like "The Last Name field cannot be blank"

How do I do that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

See Chapter 7 of the docs: http://grails.org/doc/latest/

You would change `grails-app/i18n/messages.properties` and add

```
person.lastName.blank=The Last Name field cannot be blank
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd spent a lot of time trying to track that one down - somehow I'd missed it on that page.

Comment: There's also information in each constraint page about what property name it uses - those are in the left frame in the Constraints section. E.g. the creditCard constraint uses 'className.propertyName.creditCard.invalid' - see http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/creditCard.html for a direct link.

Comment: it just don't work for me. It seems like grails version different cause this issue.

Comment: Same here with Grails 2.5.0. I can't override messages from my plugin.

Comment: I'm also seeing this issue with Grails 2.5.0 - can't over-ride messages from plugin

Comment: Re: different grails version - Try searching for "Validation and Internationalization" in grails doc for your version.

Answer (score 1):

In Grails 3 you need to change in **grails-app/i18n/messages.properties**:

**default.blank.message**=The {0} field cannot be blank