# How do I create a custom validator with a custom error message in Grails?

Tags: grails, validation, custom-errors

How do I create a custom validator in grails and make it pass a custom string back to the view and an error message?

I saw so many people getting stuck in the same please, I decided to create a question and an answer to deal with it.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### Step 1: Create a Domain Object or Command Object and put custom constrains on it, as such...

```
@grails.validation.Validateable
class PeopleCommand {

    String  firstName 
    String  lastName
    String  emailAddress
    String  idNumber

    static constraints = {
        firstName (blank: false)
        lastName  (blank: false)
        emailAddress  (blank: false)
        idNumber  (blank: false, size: 13..16, validator: {value, object ->
                if (!value.startsWith('77')) return false;
        })
    }
}
```

This will check if the idNumber you entered starts with 77. If it doesn't, it will send an error. Next question, how do we display the error?

### Step 2: Customize the View to Display your Error

```
<div class="${hasErrors(bean:person,field:'idNumber','error')}">
    <label class="control-label">Identity Number</label>
    <input value="${fieldValue(bean:person,field:'idNumber')}" name="idNumber" type="text"/>
    <div class="error-messages">
        <g:renderErrors bean="${command}" as="list" field="idNumber"/>   
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above example, `${hasErrors(bean:person,field:'idNumber','error')}` will add the string `error` to the html class if the person model object's idNumber field has an error. This class can be used to style the input and show and/or hide the `div.error-messages` block. The `<g:renderErrors bean="${command}" as="list" field="idNumber"/>` will display a horrid error message.

### Step 3: Create a Sexy Custom Message

> **IMPORTANT**: Grails does not allow you to send a message directly to the
>   view. Instead, you have to declare the message in /i18n/messages.properties (Message Bundles). You can use any key you like.

**In messages.properties**

```
validation.idStartsWith77=Your ID number must start with 77
```

**In the validator**

```
idNumber  (blank: false, size: 13..16, validator: {value, object ->
    return 'validation.idStartsWith77'
})
```

This now passes a *reference* to the view, pointing to your custom message in messages.properties...

### Step 4: Hack the system to allow passing a message directly to the view

*This only applies to people that are specifically **not** developing a multi-language web site.*

Grails allows you to pass custom parameters to the parser. You can refer to these custom parameters within your messages file. To cheat the system, we can create a custom message, where the whole message is one custom parameter. As such:

**In messages.properties**

```
validation.customRuntimeMessage={3}
```

**In the validator**

```
idNumber  (blank: false, size: 13..16, validator: {value, object ->
    return ['validation.customRuntimeMessage', 'You need to start your ID with 77']
})
```

Comment: This is awesome! Now my field is displaying the custom error msg. **BUT**, it is also displaying the default error message from the `messages.properties` file. For example, I customized the null message in my validator, when i run my code i get my customized message & the `default.null.message`. How can I make the default message NOT to show up?! Thanks!

Comment: @AlwaysANovice The answer is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922611/how-can-i-override-the-default-error-message-in-grails

Answer (score 2):

The alternative to have custom validation is create custom constraint and wire it with Grails.

http://www.zorched.net/2008/01/25/build-a-custom-validator-in-grails-with-a-plugin/

Comment: Wow, that's impressive, but just too much PT for my needs :)