# how to create your message about error for the standard validator?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

[How do I create a custom validator with a custom error message in Grails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038905/how-do-i-create-a-custom-validator-with-a-custom-error-message-in-grails/14038908#14038908)

here says how created its message about error for validator. how to create its message about error for the standard validator?

thank and sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/validation.html#validationAndInternationalization):

```
[Class Name].[Property Name].[Constraint Code]
```

For example you've provided, it'll be in i18n file:

```
personSignUpCommand.password.blank = First name should not be blank
```

Also you can see in debug all codes for validation error. Just call validate() check **errors** property of domain instance.

Comment: Thanks, but I doing so and always it show me default error message.

Comment: <g:hasErrors bean="${user}">
       <g:renderErrors bean="${user}" as="list"/></br>
</g:hasErrors>

Comment: PersonSignUpCommand.password.blank = Поле не может быть пустым

Comment: Ok, can you provide domain class with constraints?

Comment: class PersonSignUpCommand {
    String nickname
    String email
    String password
    String confirmPassword

    static constraints = {
        email blank: false, unique: true, email: true
        password blank: false
        confirmPassword blank: false, validator: { confirm, urc ->
        confirm == urc.password ?:'invalid.password'

Comment: Thanks, but I get default message :(

Comment: I guess the problem can be that you validate command object but show errors for domain

Comment: Pass command to view and render errors for it, instead of domain <g:renderErrors bean="${personSignUpCommand}" as="list"/>

Comment: def sign(PersonSignUpCommand psuc) {.................  respond view: 'signup', model: [user: psuc]

Comment: Then stop in debugger and see error codes. In other case the problem not in validation error code