# grails add validation error to hasErrors

Tags: grails, groovy

I'd like to know how to add a custom error to the hasErrors method so that the gsp picks up the error. My code thus far.

```
def recoverySetup = new RecoverySetup(params)

def onesolOrgkey = OnesolOrgkeyInfo.get(new OnesolOrgkeyInfo(params));

if(onesolOrgkey != null) {
    recoverySetup.setOneSolOrgkey(onesolOrgkey)
} else {
    recoverySetup.errors.reject('orgkey', 'You must provide a valid Org Key')
}

recoverySetup.validate()

if(recoverySetup.hasErrors()) {
    render view: 'create', model: [recoverySetupInstance: recoverySetup]
    return
}
```

Comment: why not put a custom validator rule on the RecoverySetup domain object?

Comment: There is a database query that checks to see of onesolOrgKey is null. I'm not sure how'd id do that in the domain object.

Comment: Instead of using the actual domainObject, you could imitate it in your src folder and set all that happen to the bean and part of its validation like: return errors.rejectValue(propertyName,"invalid.$propertyName",[''] as Object[],'') https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-bean-validation-examples/blob/master/src/groovy/testing/U2Bean.groovy#L19 where propertyName in the validation bean is field Name that it will represent in the gsp and then you need to match it via the gsp checks

Comment: My apology, but I'm very new to grails and I'm not following you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038905/how-do-i-create-a-custom-validator-with-a-custom-error-message-in-grails might be of help, you need both the gsp elements and your controller/validation method to bind up fields

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Danilo says, you probably want to add a constraint to your domain class to do that for you.

Learn more about constraints in http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.2.x/guide/single.html#constraints and http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.2.x/ref/Constraints/Usage.html .

If for whatever reason you really want to add a custom error that cannot be covered by the constraints (I can't imagine a case right now, but that doesn't mean it doesn't exists :-), you can still do it in a very similar fashion of what you posted:

```
instance.errors.rejectValue(fieldName, errorCode, message, defaultMessage)
instance.errors.reject(errorCode, message, defaultMessage)
```

The first rejects a concrete field, the second the bean in general. But bear in mind **this errors will be reset when you invoke `validate` again**.

Also, you can display the errors of a bean automatically in grails with:

```
<g:hasErrors bean="${instance}">
   <g:renderErrors bean="${instance}" />
</g:hasErrors>
```

See all the options here: https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.2.x/ref/Tags/hasErrors.html

Comment: I would only add to that : instance.errors.reject(errorCode, message, defaultMessage) where message is your objects bound to error code.. so instance.errors.reject('invalid.date.range.error', [date1,date2] as Object[], "Date range ${date1} - ${date2} is inavlid"). This will now look for invalid.date.range.error=Invalid input {0} {1} dates invalid.. or something in messages.properties

Answer (score 2):

Your domain class could look something like this:

```
class RecoverySetup {
    String someField
    static hasOne = [oneSolOrgkey: OneSolOrgkey]

    static constraints = {
        oneSolOrgkey nullable: false
    }
}
```

This way you declare that every instance of `RecoverySetup` is valid only if `oneSolOrgkey` is defined.

Once you have an instance of RecoverySetup you can check if it is valid by invoking the `validate()` method which returns a boolean:

```
if (recoverySetupInstance.validate()) {
    // do something with a valid object
}
else {
    recoverySetupInstance.errors.allErrors.each {err ->
        println err // Print errors
    }
}
```

if you pass the instance to a view, you will have all errors available in `recoverySetupInstance.errors` and you can display errors as you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question *I'd like to know how to add a custom error to the hasErrors method so that the gsp picks up the error* is a bit closed, in that it specifically mentions the *hasErrors* as the way you want to do it.

Another, much simpler, approach is to just create a flash message in your controller before you return to the gsp

```
flash.error = 'You must provide a valid Org Key'
render view: 'create', model: [recoverySetupInstance: recoverySetup]
return
```

Then in your gsp, a block to show that *flash.error* ...

```
<g:if test="${flash.error}">
<div class="errors" role="status">${flash.error}</div>
</g:if>
```

This works nicely for those business rule validations that you don't necessarily want to build into your objects, e.g. I used this when I wanted to prevent users accidentally adding duplicates, to a table that could allow duplicates in other cases.

Comment: The downside of this approach is that it prevents further validation and only informs about this one error. Adding an error message to object.errors would allow to inform the user about all validation errors at once.